# Relation inside a relation prolog

Tags: prolog

can we have a relation inside a relation defined in prolog?

like i have a relation defined as below:

```
relation(CctypeInt,[0-{2,3,4}, 1-{2,3,4}, 2-{2}],Ru1),!.
```

now there is one more variable which is dependeant on both CctypeInt and Ru1

so i am thinking of something like

```
relation(cctypeint,relation(ru1,...,ru2))
```

is this possible?

Comment: A good thing would be to add context to your question. What are you trying to acheive?

Answer (score 3):

Relations are defined by predicates in Prolog. There is no built-in (but you could do it for example by using term expansion) syntactic way to define predicates inside predicates in program text, and there seems little reason to do so. You can simply write separate predicates and refer to them. You *can* of course have nested terms, that is terms as subterms of other terms.

What do you mean with

```
relation(CctypeInt,[0-{2,3,4}, 1-{2,3,4}, 2-{2}],Ru1),!.
```

? This is a clause that states something about the predicate (,)/2 , which I doubt was the intention. On the other hand, you can of course build and use a Prolog term like

```
relation(cctypeint,relation(ru_1,...,ru_n))
```

in your programs to represent your data.

Comment: ,could you show me some precise example where the relation inside a relation ahs been used? or atleast a link would be helpful

Comment: There is no built-in way to do it. Use separate predicates to define different relations.